# How does quadrea relate to area?

Tags: geometry, number-theory, quadratics, rational-numbers

In NJ Wildeberger's book (which I don't see much use in citing, since its an offline material, so instead I will provide a link to his key points further down) he argues that "Quadrance" can be just as useful as "Distance". He defines Quadrance as: "A squared plus B squared" & "(((C - A)^2)+((B - D)^2)) given lines 'AB' and 'CD'. 
More info here: " https://www.quora.com/Is-N-J-Wildberger-a-joke-or-a-genius-when-he-claims-that-mathematics-in-its-current-form-is-a-hoax " & here: " https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_trigonometry " . Now knowing quadrance fills the shoes of distance; what fills the shoes of area? And how can it be converted back into its 'non-rational' equivalent?

Comment: You need to give more context. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_trigonometry#Quadrance), this is a relatively obscure topic in mathematics and I think that "quadrea" is not even part of the standard theory of rational trigonometry.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Okay, is it alright if I spend a couple hours thinking about how to reframe it in the clearest possible context? Or should I just delete my question and try all over again? (I'm new)

Comment: I think you can rework the question. That will bump it.

Comment: I have source material I could cite, but I made the mistake of assuming that it was common knowledge

Comment: Alright; I will re-work it, but due to limited char space I'm gonna need to put strategy into it

Comment: In the mean-time; it may help you understand my plight: if you look-up: "N J Wildberger", he is how I became introduced to these topics. He comes off as a bit of a quack, but he's a respectable eccentric I assure you. You don't have to, I just have trouble going quick, and don't want to be accused of trolling; I'm getting around to phrasing my main question

Comment: I reworked the question, please provide me with with feedback on any more issues that arise with it, and note: I am on a mobile device, and do not yet know how to do the TeX formatting, but: learning to do so is a goal of mine (that's why I tried to keep the appearing equations to a minimum, so as to avoid transgression)

Comment: I just [now] [after posting my main question] discovered this video, [ https://youtu.be/QlFair1X7uM ] , and it appears to contain the answer to my question, but I still feel like I need some confirmation from somebody more knowledgable [than myself] to help me make sure that I'm getting it. Basically: I suspect the answer is in this video, but to me it is buried there, whilst to somebody else: it may be plain as day; so does the stuff in this video answer my question? How?

Comment: Apparently quadrance is just the square of distance? If so wouldn't "quadrea" just be the square of area?

Comment: @Rahul that was my question. Does it describe some sort of cubic prism / 3Dimensional-object, or what?

Comment: No it wasn't. Where in the question do you mention the square of area?

Comment: It was in the old question. I edited it to clarify another  bigger ambiguity (someone told me that I needed to define what I meant by "Quadrea", so I did my best to work in my context's definition of 'quadrea'), and I guess I created a new ambiguity without realizing it, due an oversight error, and forgetting to put every piece of the question's original body text back in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of quadrea is $ (Q_1+Q_2+Q_3)^2-2(Q_1^2+Q_2^2+Q_3^2).\;$ If $\;d_21^2=Q_1,\;$ $d_2^2=Q_2,$ $d_3^2=Q_3$, then it is $(d_1+d_2+d_3)(-d_1+d_2+d_3)(d_1-d_2+d_3)(d_1+d_2-d_3)$ and by Heron's formula this is $16$ times the square of the area of the triangle.

This can be checked by looking at an equilateral triangle side $d$ whose area squared is $\frac3{16}d^4.$

Comment: Okay, to make sure my really base level stuff is still on point: to [conventionally] measure the area of a parrallelogram: you take all 4 points, measure their distance in an 'X'-shaped configuration (ie: measure its diagonals); then you divide the longest diagonal by 2, store that in variable "N"; and then multiply the shorter diagonal by variable "N". Correct?

Comment: If so, with quadrances what am I using/doing instead? Cos I only needed two distances... so, am I gonna just treat the quadrance based-solution like a "△" shaped point network, rather than the "V" shaped point network [that I used with distance on the diagonals to find the area in the previous comment]? I'm having trouble seeing which two points the third quadrance connects... ...I need help understanding this, so I can move past it